# checkbox returning blank value in a django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have defined a BooleanField in my model class. I try to set the value using a checkbox in my django template, but I get a blank value in my view after submitting the form.

the declaration in the model class is:

```
enable = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

my code in the template is as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="enable" id="enable" value="{{enable}}" /> Enable
```

Upon submitting the form, I try to access it like this in the method in the view:

```
enabled = request.POST['enable']
print enabled
```

How can I retrieve the value of the checkbox?

Comment: you say you get a "blank value" in your view... do you mean an empty string `""`?  have you checked what value you are really putting into the HTML via `{{ enable }}` ?

Comment: i get an empty string

Comment: so in the template `{{ enable }}` has no value. why not show us your view code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked status of the checkbox should be set via `checked` attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="enable" id="enable" value="on"
                             {% if enable %}checked="checked"{% endif %} />
```

Another question is: how do you pass `enable` variable to template context?  I suspect that you pass some model instance.  If yes then you should use `enabled` as the property of this instance:

```
{% if obj.enable %}checked="checked"{% endif %}
```

Where `obj` is the name of your object.

To get the value of checkbox use `get()` method.  You can even coerce it to boolean:

```
enabled = bool(request.POST.get('enable'))
```

And I also suggest to use django forms instead of manual html manipulation. It is much easier and safer.

Comment: now, i am getting the value "on" when i check the checkbox, and when i do not check it, i get an error as that post parameter is not set

Comment: @user2739737 that is expected behaviour. you can do `enabled = request.POST.get('enable')` to avoid having an exception... `enabled` will then be either `"on"` or `None`